# Word boundary metacharacter (\b) changes regular expression behavior unexpectedly

Tags: ruby, regex

I am modifying a complex regular expression that extracts URLs from text in Ruby 2.1.1.

I have found that the presence of the \b metacharacter alters the behavior of a particular part of the regex that deals with paths.

```
str = "/foo/bar/"
str =~ /((?:\/\w+)+\/?)/   # 0
$1                         # => "/foo/bar/"

str =~ /((?:\/\w+)+\/?)\b/ # 0
$1                         # => "/foo/bar"
```

Why? I would expect that the /? is greedy, and would capture the trailing slash in spite of the presence of the \b at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You are right: the `?` quantifier is greedy**

At first, the engine greedily matches the trailing slash `/`. The engine then advances both in the pattern and in the string, but at that new position (after the trailing `/`), it is unable to match the next token `\b`. That is because `\b` can only match between a word-character (letter, digit or underscore) and a non-word char or the beginning or end of a string: it cannot match after the `/`—unless there were a word character following it.

**The engine backtracks and drops the optional trailing slash**

Since the `\b` cannot match, in order to return a match, the engine attempts to backtrack. It backtracks and drops the optional trailing slash. This allows the `\b` to match after the `r`, explaining `/foo/bar`.

Comment: +1 Exactly the point. Many people just use `\b` anywhere in the regex.

Comment: Thank you, @anubhava. By the way IMO Rich makes a good point about the optional `?` being greedy, something that not everyone knows. In the same vein, the quantifier `.{3,6}` is greedy too. I know you know this btw, just wanting to add that to the comment thread. :)

Comment: Stack Overflow works its magic once again. For the record, I solved this problem by adding another condition to the section of the regex that represents "end of URL": (?<=\/)(?=\s|$)